# Can a single component of a page be full screen in winui3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

This is a video stream playing module implemented by canvas. How to make the following CanvasControl display in full screen in winui 3?

```
<Grid>
     <canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas"></canvas:CanvasControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you want the control to fill up the full main window, or do you want the app to fill the whole screen?

Comment: I want the control can fill the main window.

Comment: This is the opposite of what you say in your comment to the answer below. I.e. your question is unclear. If your question is unclear, we cannot give you a good answer. Please clarify (not in the comments. Edit the question body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a full-screen window this way. You'll need to add your `CanvasControl` to both of them.

**FullScreenWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="FullScreen.FullScreenWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:FullScreen"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button
            Click="CloseButton_Click"
            Content="Close" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**FullScreenWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;

namespace FullScreen;

public sealed partial class FullScreenWindow : Window
{
    public FullScreenWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
        ThisAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
        ThisAppWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
    }

    public static AppWindow? ThisAppWindow;

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="FullScreen.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Launch full-screen window" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace FullScreen;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private FullScreenWindow? fullScreenWindow;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fullScreenWindow = new();
        fullScreenWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

BTW, we have [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/preview-channel#winui-3) for playing videos.

**UPDATE**

This way you can pass a control to the other `Window`. This works with a `TextBox` so I guess it should work with your `CanvasControl` too.

**FullScreenWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="FullScreen.FullScreenWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:FullScreen"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button
            Click="CloseButton_Click"
            Content="Close" />
        <Grid x:Name="InputBoxControlGrid" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**FullScreenWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;

namespace FullScreen;

public sealed partial class FullScreenWindow : Window
{
    public static AppWindow? ThisAppWindow;

    public FullScreenWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
        ThisAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
        ThisAppWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
    }

    private UIElement? InputBoxControl { get; set; }

    public void InstallInputBoxControl(UIElement inputBoxControl)
    {
        InputBoxControl = inputBoxControl;
        this.InputBoxControlGrid.Children.Add(InputBoxControl);
    }

    public UIElement? UninstallInputBoxControl()
    {
        this.InputBoxControlGrid.Children.Remove(InputBoxControl);
        UIElement? inputBoxControl = this.InputBoxControl;
        this.InputBoxControl = null;
        return inputBoxControl;
    }

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="FullScreen.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:FullScreen"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Launch full-screen window" />
        <ContentControl x:Name="InputBoxContainer">
            <TextBox />
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace FullScreen;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private FullScreenWindow? FullScreenWindow { get; set; }

    public void InstallInputBoxControl(UIElement inputBoxControl)
    {
        this.InputBoxContainer.Content = inputBoxControl;
    }

    public UIElement? UninstallInputBoxControl()
    {
        UIElement? inputBoxControl = this.InputBoxContainer.Content as UIElement;
        this.InputBoxContainer.Content = null;
        return inputBoxControl;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FullScreenWindow = new();

        if (UninstallInputBoxControl() is UIElement content)
        {
            FullScreenWindow.InstallInputBoxControl(content);
        }

        FullScreenWindow.Closed += FullScreenWindow_Closed;
        FullScreenWindow.Activate();
    }

    private void FullScreenWindow_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender is FullScreenWindow fullScreenWindow)
        {
            if (fullScreenWindow.UninstallInputBoxControl() is UIElement inputBoxControl)
            {
                this.InputBoxContainer.Content = inputBoxControl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want this control to fill the full screen, not the application.Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: According to your method, the goal is achieved in effect, but the function related to full screen screen is equivalent to executing twice, which is not very friendly in actual use. In addition, what I use CanvasControl here is a function of parsing rtsp video streams. I don't know whether MediaPlayer can also parse rtsp video streams. If so, please give me your advice. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if the ``MediaPlayer`` supports rtsp video streams. So I updated my answer with a way you can pass your ``CanvasControl`` to the other ``Window``.